# Playwright not receiving event

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, playwright

I have an issue with playwright's [page.waitForEvent()](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-event):

I'd like my tests to wait for a specific event fired by our app after navigating to a different page after clicking a link. There is a component on a newly-navigated-to page that takes time to load and we fire a custom event that signals that it's ready to be used.

The event firing looks like this:

```
const event = new Event('componentReady')
window.dispatchEvent(event)
```

In my playwright tests I'm trying to wait for this event, as per [documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-event):

```
const [frame, _] = await Promise.all([
    this.page.waitForEvent('componentReady'),
    this.page.locator('button').click(),
])
```

The problem is that my tests hang and eventually timeout at this `page.waitForEvent()` without detecting my `'componentReady'` event. Has anyone experimented with `page.waitForEvent()` before? Is there something wrong I'm doing here?

Currently my tests just wait for some predefined time, but with different network conditions and on different hardware it's sometimes too much of a wait and it wastes time, or too little of a wait resulting in failing tests, since stuff has not loaded yet. Obviously this is not ideal and I'd like to avoid this by use of proper signaling.

Note: I've verified that event is actually being fired, making a listener that prints to console.

```
window.addEventListener('componentReady', (e) => { console.log('Fired event "componentReady"', e) })
```

Indeed, when playwright clicks on the button, I can see that the message below is being printed to console. I've even injected the listener above during test runtime via `page.evaluate()` and if I pause test execution and open DevTools -> Console of the browser that playwright is running in, I also can see console output.

I can't seem to find any other reports of issues with `page.waitForEvent()` so I will be grateful for any advice or pointers to resources that may help.

Comment: `waitForEvent` (and similar methods) does not wait for any HTML event - it only waits for Playwright's events: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76375821/9313033

Comment: Thanks, that did not occur to me when reading the doc.