# Playwright + Django: how to wait for events

Tags: django, pytest-django, playwright-python

In my tests, I have to wait for an event to trigger before continuing with test assertions, but I can't figure out how to make Playwright wait for that event. It seems like Playwright can't see the event.

Simple example with a django page: clicking the button fires an event `boop` that changes the background color of the document.

Template `event.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Playwright Events</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Click me</button>
  <script>
    const btn = document.querySelector("button");
    btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => document.dispatchEvent(new Event("boop")));
    document.addEventListener("boop", (e) => { document.body.style.backgroundColor = "darkcyan"; });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

URL conf:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="event.html"))
]
```

The test:

```py
def test(page, live_server):
    page.goto(live_server.url)
    page.wait_for_timeout(500)
    btn = page.get_by_text('Click me')
    with page.expect_event("boop", timeout=1000):
        btn.click()
    page.wait_for_timeout(500)
```

When running the test in headed mode, you can see the background color changing - meaning that the event `boop` was fired. But the test still fails because `expect_event` times out:
`playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError: Timeout 1000ms exceeded while waiting for event "boop"`

I must be doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what.

Found this similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73733694/playwright-not-receiving-event), but it is not about playwright-python with django.

Comment: you can verify the result of the event, check if the body has backgroundColor, class, etc

Comment: I mention that in my post; the color does change.

Comment: yes, remove `with page.expect_event...`, then click on btn after that validate if the body has background expected.

Comment: The event is fired just fine. That isn't the issue. The issue is that Playwright does not notice that the event has fired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that explicit in the [documentation](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#events) but events refer to playwright events, not HTML events.

There is no support at the moment for the functionality you describe, you could emulate it as follows though:

```py
class ExpectedHTMLEvent:
    def __init__(self, page: sync_api.Page, html_event: str, timeout_ms: float):
        self.page = page
        self.html_event = html_event
        self.timeout_ms = timeout_ms
        self.fn_name = f"setFlag{''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=6))}"
        self._flag = False
        self._end = None

    def _flag_setter(self):
        self._flag = True

    def __enter__(self) -> None:
        self.page.expose_function(self.fn_name, self._flag_setter)
        opts = "{once: true}"
        self.page.evaluate(
            f"document.addEventListener('{self.html_event}', async () => await window.{self.fn_name}(), {opts})"
        )
        self._end = datetime.now() + timedelta(milliseconds=self.timeout_ms)

    def __exit__(self, __exc_type, __exc_value, __traceback) -> None:
        while datetime.now() < self._end:
            if self._flag:
                return
            time.sleep(0.1)

        raise TimeoutError(f"'{self.html_event}' was never observed")


with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('http://example.com/')

    with ExpectedHTMLEvent(page, "boop", 2_000):
        page.evaluate("() => document.dispatchEvent(new Event('boop'))")

    with ExpectedHTMLEvent(page, "not boop", 2_000):
        page.evaluate("() => document.dispatchEvent(new Event('boop'))")
```

```
TimeoutError: 'not boop' was never observed
```

Comment: That it's only PW events didn't even occur to me. Thanks for your help.